# How to cascade an update in a one to many relationship in ef-core

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a a many to one relationship from ApiApplicant table to Api table. My Api table has the following fields:
Api: ID, name, date, isDeleted
ApiAppliant:Id,ApiID,ApplicantId,ApiRequestDate,gateId, isDeleted.
ApiId is a foreign key in ApiApplicant to Api table. Now my problem is if a user wants to delete an Api record, only the related isDeleted value should be changed to 1. and then in ApiApplicant table, the related records that has the same ApiId, should have isDeleted value to be 1 as well. I'm new in ef-core and asp.net. I appreciate if anyone sujjest me a solution by showing a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite `SaveChangesAsync` method in DbContext to update `isDeleted` value both in parent entity and children entities.Also, remember to disable the cascade delete behavior of EF core.

Refer to following steps:

**1.Models:**

```
public class Api
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //other properties

    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    public List<ApiApplicant> ApiApplicants { get; set; }
}

public class ApiApplicant
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ApiID { get; set; }//set as nullable

    //other properties

    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApiID")]
    public Api Api { get; set; }
}
```

**2.DbContext(Disable default cascade delete)**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Api> Apis { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApiApplicant> ApiApplicants { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Api>()
                    .HasMany(i => i.ApiApplicants)
                    .WithOne(c => c.Api)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        OnBeforeSaving();
        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        OnBeforeSaving();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void OnBeforeSaving()
    {


        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                if (entry.Entity is Api )
                {
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                    //change Api.isDeleted value to true
                    entry.CurrentValues["isDeleted"] = true;

                    //change navigations' isDeleted value to true
                    foreach (var c in entry.Collections)
                    {
                        if(c.Metadata.Name == "ApiApplicants")
                        {
                            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)c.CurrentValue)
                            {
                                    ((ApiApplicant)item).isDeleted = true;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3.Delete Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var api = await _context.Apis.Include(a => a.ApiApplicants).FirstOrDefaultAsync(a=>a.ID == id);
        _context.Apis.Remove(api);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Comment: @hrz I am glad that you have resolved the problem.Could you accept my answer now?